# Conditional Formatting on column based on other column value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build a simple conditional formatting that will allow me color a cell value if its value is below another cell's value in the same row.

For example -

[image: Let's take the following table]

As we can see, In Rows 2 and 5 the value of column B was lower than the value of column A and therefore it turned green.

I understand how to do a static conditional analysis such as this one:

[image]

However my goal is to apply this on the entire column and not row by row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **Apply to range** put:

```
B2:B
```

under **Format cells if...** select

```
custom formula
```

and in field type in:

```
=B2<A2
```